corrupted system files, how to recover databases for a fresh install?
newbie here. Our system files got corrupted and we no longer can access the control panel or phpmyadmin, but we do have access to SSH and FTP, and to my understanding, you can backup databases locally using the mysqldump command, however somehow MySQL's files were also corrupted and we no longer can use mysqldump.
I contacted my provider and they said this "MySQL databases are typically stored in /var/lib/mysql/. You can copy the whole mysql directory and place it into its new location".
When I searched for this folder, I did find it under www/server/mysql/ but no databases inside, I did however find a folder under www/server/data/ containing what looks like my tables with .MYD .MYI and .sdi files. Is it weird that they are on a completely separate folder than MySQL or is that by design? Can I download and upload these into a completely fresh install on a new host and get my data back?
Any tips or advice is appreciated!
We are on Ubuntu 22.04, aaPanel, in case that helps.

you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files

If your system is corrupted such that you can't use mysqldump anymore, you should probably restore from your last good backup.

If your system is corrupted such that you can't use mysqldump anymore, you should probably restore from your last good backup.
You can, in theory, move the entire MySQL data directory to a new install, but moving only parts of it (such as trying to only copy over one database) often can cause problems or not work at all. Since you have some corruption of some sort, it's tough to guess if all the parts of the database are working correctly or if some segment of your data is missing as well.
You could try to repair the database or tables from within MySQL on the current system to see if you can get mysqldump to work. I'd make a complete backup of the data directory first, too, just in case.
You can find the data directory from the MySQL prompt with select @@datadir; (at least this works in MariaDB, which is probably what you have anyway).
